# why are all my colliders triggering on my player when 1 is triggered in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am Making a project in unity where the player can climb walls and swing from ceilings and how that works is that the player has 4 triggers on each side so that when one is triggered, it tells what the state will be
[This is my player collisions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bV1mx.png)

all 4 triggers are stored in separate variables and the detection is here

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag != "Player")
    {
        if (ColliderRoof.IsTouching(collision) || collision.gameObject.tag != "couch")
        {
            State = "Swinging";
            CanJump = false;
            animator.SetBool("IsClimbing", false);
            animator.SetBool("IsSwinging", true);
            Debug.Log("Swinging");
        }
        if (ColliderLeft.IsTouching(collision) || collision.gameObject.tag != "couch")
        {
            State = "Climbing";
            isRight = false;
            CanJump = false;
            animator.SetBool("IsSwinging", false);
            animator.SetBool("IsClimbing", true);
            Debug.Log("Climbing");
        }
        if (ColliderRight.IsTouching(collision) || collision.gameObject.tag != "couch")
        {
            animator.SetBool("IsSwinging", false);
            animator.SetBool("IsClimbing", true);
            State = "Climbing";
            isRight = true;
            CanJump = false;
            Debug.Log("Climbing");
        }
        if (ColliderFloor.IsTouching(collision) || collision.gameObject.tag != "couch")
        {
            Debug.Log("Floor");
            CanJump = true;
            animator.SetBool("IsJumping", false);

        }
        else
        {
            CanJump = false;

        }
    }
}
```

I had them all as if else statements but it was only triggering the first one when any triggers collided with anything, so I turned them into if statements and whenever ANY of the triggers collide with anything it triggers all of if statements, it had worked beforehand but something happened and it stopped working.

also the '|| collision.gameObject.tag != "couch"' is because of a couch that I don't want the player to collide with.

it was working for a while but then when I changed the player to be able to become a prefab and because I had the player and the animation/avatar separate because it was easier. I also took a short break after I had made a change and when I came back I NOTICED the problem, now it might have been there before.

Comment: this code makes no sense with the picture of 1 capsule coliider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can tell you that your code would be easier, cleaner and you would also get rid of this issue, if you would have a script for every Collider, each one has a  `int triggerCount` variable which gets increased `OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)` and decreased `OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)`.
Once you have done attaching the four scripts to the colliders, you can create a Player script which handles the animations and variables based on the other four scripts.

Below you can see how I would proceed.

**Simple example of ColliderScript.cs**

```
private int triggerCount;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
     if (yourCondition)
        triggerCount++;
}
private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
{
     if (yourCondition)
        triggerCount--;
}
public bool IsTriggered(){
     return triggerCount > 0;
}
```

**Simple example of Player.cs**

```
public ColliderScript colliderFloor;
public ColliderScript colliderRight;
public ColliderScript colliderLeft;
public ColliderScript colliderRoof;

private void EvaluateState(){
     if (colliderFloor.IsTriggered())
         Debug.Log("Floor");
     //Etc...
}
```

Drag the ColliderScript references to the Player script using the inspector and you are good to go!

Comment: @StickKai I am glad it has worked! Mark the reply as answer :)